# MongoDB: Set shard key by primary access pattern

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm new in this world, so I'll appreciate your help :)

I have MongoDB sharded cluster (with 3 servers) with a lot of data, but my database is not sharded.I want to shard 1 collection (size 34GB) with 8 indexes... me questions is about the shard key...

I'm trying to identify the primary access pattern, and I found that there are two primary usage scenarios for my collection:
1. for find (on 2 fields)
2. for delete (on 1 field, different from the find)

what is best practice for that? build my shard key based on the "find" queries or on the "delete"?

Thanks

Comment: how many times is each those usage scenarios executed? and what is the nature of the fields? How does data get into the system?

Comment: how do clients get the id for deleting, do they have to call find before? so n(find) >= n(delete)?

Comment: I would also look at the types of queries performed on the collection. Are they ranged queries? The reason is that if they are ranged queries they would perform better if the data is found in the same shard, at least most of the time.

Comment: - Primary usage scenario is delete, find happens relatively rare. delete happens ~1-10 times per second
- The nature of the fields are (both not using "_id"):
       for the find: type and id
       for the delete : id (different from the id that the find use)
- Our service inserts them, there is a flow: delete old data -> insert new data which always happens together